# Input cursor that is blinking

Tags: html, css, forms

i am having trouble with making the input cursor to blink. How do you make an animation that the cursor "|" inside the input field (placeholder) keeps blinking. 
The code that i have is this:

```
<input type="text" class="rq-form-element" placeholder="|"/>
```

I have no idea on how to get this even started. Any suggestions?

Comment: placeholder="|" will just add string | into text box and gray it out, it will add no animation. You'll have to add some JS and probably create a custom element.

Comment: You need to do auto focus in text field, the purpose of place holder is different.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this solution

```
<div class="cursor">
<input type="text" class="rq-form-element" />
<i></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cursor {
    position: relative;
}
.cursor i {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: gray;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10%;
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    opacity: 1;
}

.cursor input:focus + i {
    display: none;
}

@keyframes blink {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dygxxb7n/

Comment: dont forget to add user-select: none to disable text selection on the cursor itself. ty

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to use the custom cursor. Is there a way to also use the cursor styled .cursor i to also move while the input being typed? it appears once the typing starts it defaults to the original cursor as there is a focus selector that displays none.

Answer (score 29):

Just add `autofocus` attribute. See the link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_input_autofocus.asp)

```
<input type="text" class="rq-form-element" autofocus/>
```

The `autofocus` attribute is a `boolean` attribute.
When present, it specifies that an  element should automatically get `focus` when the `page loads`.

Comment: easy and efficient

Comment: Why bother with an animation when you can take the easy way out? This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you’re looking for but you can set

```
caret-color: currentColor;
```

And it will be the same color as the text in that element. Of course you can set it to any color you want too. Hopefully that’s you match the initial cursor with the animation to the actual carat cursor when a user focuses