# How to animate and style a blinking text cursor in CSS?

Tags: css, forms, input

I'm looking to create a blinking text cursor that I also want to style to look pretty similar to the following website:

http://paul.institute/enrol

I had a look at the source but it's all written in one single line and is a bit of a mess.

Comment: Try this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input cursor that is blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481586/input-cursor-that-is-blinking)

Comment: I'm afraid these aren't quite the answer. In the website i've shared with you the cursor is blinking not the actual text itself. The blinking cursor also follows the text along the page it doesnt simply disappear when text is inputted as it does in the 'input  cursor that is blinking' thread