# Make WP plugin "Contact Form 7" text field cursor blink

Tags: wordpress, forms

Is it possible to make a `Contact Form 7` text field text cursor blink when active?

I know [there is a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481586/input-cursor-that-is-blinking) when you're creating your own contact form but I don't think I can use that method with CF7.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adapting the code, here is what it can give

```css
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: gray;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10%;
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    opacity: 1;
    content: '';
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap input:focus + .wpcf7-form-control-wrap:before {
    display: none;
}

@keyframes blink {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Sco.

Comment: Looks like the makers of CF7 have already implemented this in their plugin, no CSS required. :-)