# Setting cursor blinking automatically on ui-autocomplete-input before input is selected jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

can somebody help how to set cursor blinking automatically on ui-autocomplete-input of jQuery before input is selected. I went through documentation https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but didn't find the answer. I found only this $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "search", "" ); that automatically triggers the search(select option list), but I only need cursor blinking without triggering select option list.

Comment: Please add you sample code

Comment: what do you mean by cursor blinking?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I mean on  $(document).ready(function(){} that ui-autocomplete-input gets cursor blinking, before user has clicked on input field.

Answer (score 0):

using javascript (jquery):

```
$(element).focus(); //you can use $("textarea") for a more generic 
//do autocomplete stuff after
```

(if you're using autocomplete on pageload) using pure html:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autofocus>
<!--the "autofocus" makes elements come in focus on page load-->
```

*Specifics on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) and on [Stackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481586/input-cursor-that-is-blinking)

*This is hacky! :)
*Only keeps one element on focus at a time.

Hope I could help!

Comment: Can you possible share you code and a screenshot [here](https://codeshare.io/) or any other platform? Thanks